# Patternmatching to detect signal edge?

Tags: algorithm, signal-processing

I have a analog signal and I want to detect edges/'waveforms'. The waveforms to detect are sometimes as simple as in the first example below (simple rising edge), but also more complex (like a rising edge with a preceding smaller 'blob'). The Signal has noise and unwanted smaller signals, so a output like 'matching grade' 0.0 to 1.0 would be nice to set a threshold.
Another requirement is the detection time: The algorithm has to 'trigger' within 1 'rise time', like the red blob circle in the image. As early as possible, but not before maximum is reached.

Everything will be executed on a STM32 ARM controller, the signal has 100 points per second. A flank rising edge takes 0.5 - 2 seconds, so the data range to 'look at' would be around 250 - 500 datapoints.

I have read about correlation and FFTs, but if I understand the subject right, this will only apply to periodic waveforms (as the FFT will dismantle the signal into sin/cos parts).

Is FFT and correlation the correct path to take or are there better methods for our requirement? If our path is correct, is there recommended literature/search terms for a easy entry into the subject?

Edit:
I added examples of real data.
In [Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UMqE.png) you can see a easy to detect edge. We have no problems with this edges using a basic edge detection.

In [Picture 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAmRy.png) lies our problem:
Our current algorithm detects a edge at 2565s, but we want a detection at 2574s.
The first 'blob' always appears in with around 40% - 85% of signal level compared to the edge to detect.

[image: Sample waveforms to detect]

[image: example of good data]

[image: example of bad data]

Comment: A must before this question can be usefully answered: show real data. I know from experience that true data is *never* like an OP sketches.

Comment: I would suggest that you throw a wavelet packet transform at that, see what you get, and try to find patterns in the output.  The bottom of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavelet_packet_decomposition links to existing implementations in MATLAB, R, C++ and Java that you can try.  I would recommend avoiding being overly smooth.  A 4 tap Daubechies wavelet likely will work well.  (The Haar wavelet is too rough - it won't represent the rising edge very well.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are absolutely right that Fourier series are a bad choice because you're trying to write down a description of the data with no edges, and then discover edges in that description.  Doesn't work well.

One approach you can take is to do something like Fourier series but with descriptions that are more localized and includes things that look like edges.  Google for "wavelet edge detection" to learn a lot more about that.  This will allow you to extract a variety of forms from noisy data.  For example people use this to extract edges from pictures, and phoenemes from audio recordings.  Wavelets are a big topic, but you may be able to find a library that does something close to what you want.

But for a simple 1-d problem like this, you can simply apply a smoothing operation, then look for shapes of interest.  The better your smoothing operation, the more noise you can tolerate but the harder it becomes to see shapes.

For example you could do exponential damping for smoothing.  `next_average = 0.9 * average + 0.1 * next_value`.  (More generally `(1 - x) * average + x * next_value`.)  This will make each point into something that looks a lot like an average of a moving window of about 10 points.  Compare the average of now with 100 points ago, and you'll be able to spot a rise pretty reliably.  Some more messing around and you might spot other combinations.

You'll have to play around with the equations and your data to find something that works well enough for your purposes.